# Calling javascript in href on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

```
<a id="f_post_button" href="javascript:toggle_hide('f_post_button','f_postbox','post');">  
    <button class="btn btn-hg btn-primary">Make a Post</button>
</a>
```

This is working fine for me in safari and chrome, but in IE and Firefox it just opens a blank page. Is there any alternative way to do it?

Comment: Why do you have a link there in the first place? You're not linking anywhere with it, and it contains a button (which is forbidden). Just use a button and bind a click event handler to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a button you don't need to use href you can use onclick

Try this:

```
<button class="btn btn-hg btn-primary" onclick="toggle_hide('f_post_button','f_postbox','post')">Make a Post</button>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function3

Answer (score 1):

add void method to resolve this

```
<a id="f_post_button" href="javascript:void(toggle_hide('f_post_button','f_postbox','post'));">  
<button class="btn btn-hg btn-primary">Make a Post</button>
```

Comment: It helps me making work my function in Firefox with `javascript:`

Answer (score 0):

What is saying Quentin is something like this :

```html
<button id="my-button" class="btn btn-hg btn-primary">Make a Post</button>
```

```js
 var myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");        

 myButton.click = function (f_post_button,f_postbox,post){
     //do your stuff for toggle here
 }
```